# Elasticsearch aggregations faltam categorias nos buckets

Tags: elasticsearch, querydsl

Preciso de agregar produtos por categoria

O "body" dos produtos é:

```
p1 = [ ... "categories": ["1","2","3","4"] ];
p2 = [ ... "categories": ["2","1","9","10"] ];
p3 = [ ... "categories": ["2","22","13","14"] ];
p4 = [ ... "categories": ["14","52","36","41"] ];
```

A query de agregação corresponde a:

```
{
            "aggregations": {
                "categories.raw": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "categories.raw"
                    }
                }
            }
            ,"from" : 0, "size" : 0
}
```

No entanto os buckets não resultam com todas as categorias dos produtos.

Preciso de contar para todas as categorias, por exemplo:

```
categoria1 = 2
categoria2 = 3
...
```

Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Não vou indicar sua pergunta para reabertura **ainda** porque não consegui entender qual a dúvida. Creio que o exemplo (que infelizmente ainda está faltando) dê uma ideia melhor

Comment: Já dá para entender?

Comment: Sim, entendi agora

Comment: Consegue ajudar?